# expand div from bottom to top with animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, css-animations

i'm trying to animate button height from bottom to top and AND overlapping the div above the buttons.

so from this:
[image]

i'll get something like this:
[image]

```
 <div class="div_1"></div>
   <div class="buttons_div">
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
      <button>3</button>
   </dv>
 <div class="div_1"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21096/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are animating the height which is ok, you can also animate `margin-top` using a negative value to overlap the text *(Simply make sure the button won't go behind the text by adding a high z-index if necessary)*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function(){
   $(this).animate({'height': '100px','marginTop': '-50px'});
  });
});
```

```css
.div_1{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
button{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}
button:nth-of-type(1){
  background: yellow;
}
button:nth-of-type(2){
  background: green;
}
button:nth-of-type(3){
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essenti</div>
  <div class="buttons_div">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div_1"></div>
```